# How to use CURL to send data for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I would like to send data from one WP site to an other. 
I have two plugins the sender ad the reciver. 
In the sender side I used the init hook

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'say_hello') );

....

public function say_hello() {
$data = get_plugin_data( $this->pDIR.'/plugin.php', $markup = false, $translate = false );

$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

$fields = array(
          'action' => 'Hello_ajax',
          'zpm_hello' => '1',
          'zpm_plugin_version' => $data['Version'],
          'zpm_host' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { 
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
//close connection
curl_close($ch);

}
```

The variables are fine the url is correct I printed out. 
On the reciver side I registered the admin ajax

```
add_action('wp_ajax_Hello_ajax', array($this, 'zpm_api_hello'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_Hello_ajax', array($this, 'zpm_api_hello'));

public function zpm_api_hello() {
    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['response'] = "";
    $error = false;

    $hello          = $_POST['zpm_hello'];
    $plugin_version = $_POST['zpm_plugin_version'];
    $plugin_host    = $_POST['zpm_host'];

    if(!isset($hello)) {
        $error = true;
        $response['response'] .= "Ello >> Auth ERROR - CODE - 01 ";
    } 

    if(!isset($plugin_version)) {
        $error = true;
        $response['response'] .= "Ello >> Plugin Version error - CODE - 02 ";
    }

    if(!isset($plugin_host)) {
        $error = true;
        $response['response'] .= "Ello >> Plugin host error - CODE - 03 ";
    }


    if(!$error) {
        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['response'] .= "Ello >> Auth OK ";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

So the code is here.
My problem is when I try to load the sender site it is just loading and loading for ever and I doesn't get back the result. Could you tell me what could be the problem with this method? Thanks all of your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to use this example to build your PHP request, if you send me the POST body, headers and url parameters I will even build it for you:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://example.com//wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "blakey=blaval",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "action: Hello_ajax",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "postman-token: fd5bcc0b-f46d-0cf8-a5cf-dc83bfe7dbec",
    "zpm_hello: 1"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used this base and now it is OK.

Comment: @Thomas - Are you able to elaborate at all on what postman-token is here and how I can get it? I am attempting to make a curl request to admin-ajax.php but I am getting no response, I am assuming it is an authentication issue and I am wondering if this is the key. Many thanks

Comment: @DaveEssery You don't need a postman token, it was an example where I used postman (a helpfull debugging tool for api's). I think your problem lies somewhere else. Please create your own question and you will probably be helped!