# AJAX function that sends a e-mail as a user

Tags: wordpress

What is the right way to implement a AJAX function that sends a e-mail message as a user?

I created a prototype inside a plugin:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_vue_contact_form_send_mail_as_user', array(&$this, 'ajaxSendMailAsUser')); // non-logged-in users


public function ajaxSendMailAsUser()
{
    // Don't let IE cache this request
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Content-type: application/json");
 
    $in = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    if ($in)
    {
        $credentials = $in->credentials;
        
        $user = wp_authenticate($credentials->username, $credentials->password);

        if(!is_wp_error($user))
        {
            $to = $this->getOption('EMail');

            //$from is same as $to
            $headers = "From: {$user->display_name} <{$to}>\r\n" .
                "Reply-To: {$user->display_name} <{$user->user_email}>\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

            if (wp_mail($to, $in->subject, $in->message, $headers))
            {
                $out->status = "sent";
            }
            else
            {
                $out->status = "error";
                $out->message = "Error sending email.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $out->status = "error";
            $out->message = "Authentication failed.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $json_error = json_last_error();
        $out->status = "error";
        $out->message = "Cannot decode input. JSON error number: {$json_error}.";
    }
    
    echo json_encode($out);
    
    die();
}
```

but I am not sure about the authentication. Should I use`wp_ajax_nopriv_` prefix and `wp_authenticate` in PHP code? Or probably there is a mechanism allowing to authenticate with `wp_ajax_vue_contact_form_send_mail_as_user` and then use `$user = wp_get_current_user();` in PHP code?

And what is the function URL? (How to use it with `curl` from the command line? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33754331/2394762)